# how to merge two logs , one for the UI events and other for the SQL queries, On the event basis?

Tags: java

I need help in joining two logs using timestamp if it is possible:

[image]

Comment: are you using log4j?

Comment: Can you add more detail of what you're trying to achieve?
Or an example?